# Addning line break dynamically in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets assume I'm having a variable having this string.

```
var str = "This is line 1.This is line 2.This is line 3.";
```

My question is, can I get every sentence in a new line with dynamically adding  **< br>** tag (or anyother way) , so that output will looklike,

```
This is line 1 
This is line 2 
This is line 3
```

The answer in jquery is most welcome.

Comment: You haven't tried anything?

Comment: jQuery can't do this. JavaScript can. jQuery is not the answer to everything.

Comment: jQuery *can* do this (assuming that the OP is referring to the input string being part of the DOM), but whether it's the best tool for this particular job is a matter of opinion and circumstance within the project

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var str = "This is line 1.This is line 2.This is line 3.";
// If you want to store in the html, join by <br/>
document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = str.split(".").join("<br/>");
// If you want to paint in log, join by \n
console.log(str.split(".").join("\n"));
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: @SudhiSr - I have updated my answer covering both the cases. Choose the one that helps you and apologies for the confusion, I did not realized that you are the OP :)